# Pythonic code for cumulative sum of a time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a column `Date_of_Purchase` with many `datetime` values:

```
dop_phev = rebates[rebates['Vehicle_Type']=='Plug-in Hybrid']['Date_of_Purchase']
dop_phev
```

Output:

```
0     2015-07-20
1     2015-07-20
3     2015-07-20
4     2015-07-24
5     2015-07-24
     ...    
502   2017-09-16
503   2017-09-18
504   2017-06-14
505   2017-09-21
506   2017-09-22
Name: Date_of_Purchase, Length: 383, dtype: datetime64[ns]`
```

I want to make a plot of cumulative purchases, `y`, vs the date, `x`. I started working on a solution where I loop through each date and count all dates less than that date, but it's definitely an "un-pythonic" solution. How can I accomplish this with pythonic code?

EDIT: I'm not sure exactly what it would look like, but this is my current solution:

```
dop_phev = rebates[rebates['Vehicle_Type']=='Plug-in Hybrid']['Date_of_Purchase']
cum_count = np.zeros(len(dop_phev.unique()))
for i, date in enumerate(dop_phev.unique()):
    cum_count[i] = sum(dop_phev<date)
plt.plot(dop_phev.unique(),cum_count)
```

This doesn't quite work...

For reference, I'm studying [this dataset](https://data.delaware.gov/Energy-and-Environment/State-Rebates-for-Alternative-Fuel-Vehicles/8z8z-di7f) on rebates for electric vehicles. You can find a CSV of the data on my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/petermattia/Delaware-EVs/blob/master/State_Rebates_for_Alternative-Fuel_Vehicles.csv).

Comment: Heard of `cumsum`?

Comment: Can you add some data sample with desired output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : For MATLAB, but not for Python ;). Can you demonstrate how it would work for dates? I tried `np.cumsum(dop_phev)` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and then [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
dop_phev = dop_phev.groupby(dop_phev).apply(lambda x: sum(dop_phev<x.name))
print (dop_phev)
2015-07-20    0
2015-07-24    3
2017-06-14    5
2017-09-16    6
2017-09-18    7
2017-09-21    8
2017-09-22    9
Name: Date_of_Purchase, dtype: int64

dop_phev.plot()
```